# Can I pipe my node.js script output in to `less` without typing `| less` when run?

Tags: node.js, bash

For example, my script will generate a lot of output using `process.stdout.write()`. I know I can pipe them into `less` by running it as `node mycode.js | less -N`.

But is there a way so that I can do the piping inside of my code, so that other people can run my code normally `node mycode.js` and still get my output piped into `less`?

Comment: I think you should edit your title to more accurately reflect your question. (From your title it sounds like you don't know what you are doing and need to be told `node script.js | less`.) Also FWIW, I think many users might hate this behavior.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Actually I'm trying to write a helper script for my server. Because we have a lot of big tables (2G+ CSV/TSV files), we need a script to serve as a "viewer" and "formator", essentially being a tool that reads the file while piping it to `less`.

Answer (score 3):

Among the four APIs from node's built-in `child_process`, you would want to use `spawn` that gives you the choice to run `less` in the current shell which invokes the script. All other choices like `exec`, `fork` will simply start a new invisible shell.

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

spawn(`cat <<< "${yourOutputString}" | less -r`, {   // <<< read the *HERE* string to cat
                                                     // less -r specifies colored output
            stdio: 'inherit', // use the current shell for stdio
            shell: true
    });
```

Now you can invoke your script simply with `node script.js`.

This lengthy [tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a) gives you a thorough view of the `child_process` API.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Tested this on Node 18.5 and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pipe the output of your node program into the input less via the normal `child_process` core module's API. However, the issue will be the controlling pty. If you are running your node program, it will control the pty and less won't have access to the pty, so interacting with less by typing commands won't work. AFAIK (others may very well know better than I) there's no clean way to do this from within your node program, so I would just write a wrapper shell script to do it and call it done.

The closest possibility I found in npm is [default-pager](https://github.com/dominictarr/default-pager) but from my quick test harness, it does not seem to work. :-(

Comment: Thank you. And that's exactly what I'm doing at the moment. The problem is that now I want to add a `if` statement and if some condition is not satisfied I want to stop the piping and output to bash instead. I don't know how should I do that.

Comment: Let me just make an aside that in the decades of unix programs, there are basically no widely-adopted programs that do this or anything like it. Unix has a philosophy and this kind of this is expressly condemned. Unix users know how to pipe to less if they want to. My gut says your task here is a fools errand, but don't take that as discouragement - I just want to make sure you have the broader perspective available.

Comment: I just want to reiterate that what @PeterLyons is saying here is exactly what I was trying to express in my comment. There are **certainly** use cases for going straight into a pager -- man pages do this. However, there's a reason that `|` exists in Unix to begin with. Since any command you enter at a Linux terminal can effectively become a one-line bash script, you could have your users execute a bash script that only says (besides the shebang line) `node script.js | less`.

Comment: And if you need `if`/`else` conditions, bash is basically a fully functional programming language. Shell scripting is certainly capable of meeting your use case if `node.js` is not.

Comment: @peterlyons: I take it that you are not fond of the 'man' command-line utility.

Comment: man is written in C AFAIK. I don't believe the ability to replace the current process the way man does is available in node, but again I could be wrong. FWIW no the man program and man pages are and always have been crap. WWW FTW.

Comment: @PeterLyons: I'll give you another example: git log. FWIW, the mechanism is not important. What he wants is to have less-compatible navigation of large text files. If it can be done by piping to less (I can easily do that in tcl so the explanation about pty above is invalid, if a language wants to implement this feature it can) or it can be done via some sort of readline type library.

Comment: @slebetman how about posting an answer? piping node's stdout to less's stdin does not behave as if less know's the pty dimensions nor as if less can see any of the keystrokes.

Comment: @PeterLyons: I don't know how to do it in node. But in tcl for example, the `exec` function (similar to node's `child_process`) can redirect the pty's stdin and stdout to the child process directly (not the interpreter's stdin and stdout). This is the same mechanism that bash/ksh/zsh/csh etc. use to execute programs in the foreground and allow that program to take over the terminal. Therefore one cannot say that it can't be done. You may need to write a module in C to do it but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* possible from within Node, if you're willing to use a compiled extension: [node-kexec](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-kexec).

I preform almost precisely the tasks you want to [in my project's executable](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/Paws.js/blob/16cf69b5/Executables/paws.js.coffee#L197-L227) as follows (forgive the CoffeeScript):

```
page = (cb)->

   # If we reach this point in the code and $_PAGINATED is already set, then we've
   # successfully paginated the script and should now actually run the code meant
   # to be run *inside* a pager.
   if process.env['_PAGINATED']?
      return cb()

   # I use tricks like this to control the pager itself; they can be super-dirty,
   # though, and mutating shell-command lines without a *lot* of careful
   # invocation logic is generally a bad idea unless you have a good reason:
   pager = process.env.PAGER || 'less --chop-long-lines'
   pager = pager.replace /less(\s|$)/, 'less --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS$1'

   # I use this elsewhere in my code-base to override `term.columns` if it is
   # unset; because the pager often doesn't properly report terminal-width
   process.env['PAGINATED_COLUMNS'] = term.columns
   process.env['_PAGINATED'] = 'yes'

   # This is a horrible hack. Thanks, Stack Overflow.
   #    <https://stackoverflow.com/a/22827128>
   escapeShellArg = (cmd)-> "'" + cmd.replace(/\'/g, "'\\''") + "'"

   # This is how we *re-invoke* precisely the exact instructions that our script /
   # executable was originally given; in addition to ensuring that `process.argv`
   # is the same by doing this, `kexec` will already ensure that our replacement
   # inherits our `process.stdout` and etc.
   #
   # (These arguments are invoked *in a shell*, as in `"sh" "-c" ...`, by
   # `kexec()`!)
   params = process.argv.slice()
   params = params.map (arg)-> escapeShellArg arg
   params.push '|'
   params.push pager

   log.debug "!! Forking and exec'ing to pager: `#{pager}`"
   log.wtf "-- Invocation via `sh -c`:", params.join ' '

   kexec params.join ' '
```

This is invoked as simply as you'd expect; something like `page(print_help_text)` (which is how I'm using it).

There's also a couple obvious gotchas: it's not going to magically fork your program *where it is invoked*, it's going to re-execute the entire program up to the point where it got invoked; so you'll want to make sure that anything happening *before* invoking `page()` is deterministic in nature; i.e. precisely the same things will occur if the program is re-invoked with the same set of command-line arguments. (It's a convenience, not magic.) You probably also want to make sure the code leading up to `page()` is idempotent, i.e. doesn't have any undesired side-effects when run twice.

(If you want to do this without compiling a native extension, try and get Node core to add an `exec` function like Ruby's. `:P`)

---

> **Nota bene:** If you *do* decide to do this, please make it configurable with the standard `--[no-]pager` flag. Pagers can be a nice convenience, but not everybody wants to use one.
>
> On the same note, please realize that compiled dependencies can cause a lot of people trouble; personally, I keep `kexec` in my `package.json`'s `optionalDependencies`, and then [use a `try/catch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17566436) (or a convenience like [`optional`](https://github.com/tony-o/node-optional)) to source it. That way, if it fails to install on the user's system, your code still runs as expected, just without the nicety of the pager.

Comment: A better implementation is to detect the terminal instead of using a command line flag. Like how git log is implemented (or for that matter less itself)

Comment: Oh, eek, I just assumed checking `isTTY` is a given; I didn't even think that he might try to invoke a pager when the `stdout` isn't a TTY. Thanks for the note, I feel foolish for not noting that. I still absolutely do not feel that is enough, though; `--no-pager` isn't for scripts which are piping; it's for people who *don't want to use a pager*, for any reason.