# Vue image binding converts a asset path into a string

Tags: image, vue.js, src

I've been working on some code that should dynamically add one part of a path to another part of a path. However, Vue seems to think that the :src path is a string instead of a path.

Here's the code:

`<img:src="'@/assets/images/' + this.params.img" >`

The `this.params.img` is basically what adds the second part from inside the modal I created:

```
this.$modal.show('modal-newreminder', {
           title: this.$i18n.t('firstReminderTitle'),
           text: this.$i18n.t('firstReminderText'),
           img: 'onboarding/onboarding-2.svg'
        });
```

Chrome's inspect element screenshot:

[[image]]

I've tried doing this as well:

```
<img :src=" require(`@/assets/images/${this.params.img}`) " />
```

But no luck so far

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share codepen of this please.

Comment: [See the comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881406/3585500). Maybe that's the syntax you're after?