# Vue.js - vue-cli-service serve - img src not loading correctly from object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have been looking at the following question but I can't get images to load correctly when setting `src` from an object.

[How can I use 'img src' in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880956/how-to-use-img-src-in-vue-js)

I created a new Vue project with TypeScript using the following guide:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

1. Install Vue CLI, if it's not already installed

   npm install --global @vue/cli
2. Create a new project, then choose the "Manually select features" option

   vue create my-project-name

I choose to add every feature for this project:

[image]

When running this code I can see an image for the hard coded `src` but not the dynamic `:src` loaded from an object. Could this be due to Babel or CSS-Pre-processor? I choose to use `Sass/SCSS (with dart-sass)` as a CSS-Pre-processor.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img class="center" :src="test.imageSrc" alt="image" />
        <img class="center" :src="test.imageSrcLocalFolder" alt="image" />
        <img class="center" src="./a1-1.png" alt="image" />
        <img class="center" src="../assets/a1-1.png" alt="image" />
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
        private test = {
            imageSrc: '../assets/a1-1.png',
            imageSrcLocalFolder: './a1-1.png',
        }

    }
</script>
```

Inspecting elements look like this:

[image]

I start the dev server running `npm run serve` as described in the `README.md` file and in the documentation. This calls the script `vue-cli-service serve` from `package.json`.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html

README.md:

````
### Compiles and hot-reloads for development
```
npm run serve
```
````

Comment: did you try `<img class="center" :src="require(test.imageSrcLocalFolder)" alt="image" />`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Error in runtime: `Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './a1-1.png'"`

Comment: you should respect the relative path

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use an asset you need to use `require` so the path gets resolved to a runtime accessible path.

When you are adding the `src` in the template part it get's parsed and in the end it will be wrapped around an `require`.

You need to add `require` to your path.

Comment: Thank you, using `private test = { imageSrc: require('../assets/a1-1.png') }` worked!