# Bind `id` to img src url using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm new to vue, and trying to follow a tutorial.
I'm trying to pull the image through that relates to the id of my article.

Everything else is coming through ok, `article.id` etc. The image will have the same filename as the `article.id` for the time being, so I just want to pull it into the component.

```
<div class="card bg-dark mb-2" v-for="article in articles" v-bind:key="article.id">
  <div class="card-body">
    <img class="card-img-top" v-bind:src="images/articles/`{{ $article.id }}`.jpg" width="100%" alt="Card image cap" />
    <h5 class="card-title  text-white">{{ article.id }}. {{ article.title }}</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-white-50">{{ article.from }}</h6>
    <p class="card-text text-truncate" style="max-width: 150px;">{{ article.description }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-right">
    <small class="text-white-50">Added by <span class="text-white">{{ article.added_by }}</span> ({{ article.created_at }})</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I need to provide anything else to this post.

**Update:**

I don't know if it makes a difference, but the `article.id` I'm using is being fetched from the Laravel API I've created.

The `#app` div is in in my `index.blade.php` file

```
export default {
data() {
  return {
    articles: [],
    article: {
      id: '',
      title: '',
      description: '',
      from: '',
      rating: '',
      from: '',
      created_at: '',
      added_by: ''
    },
    recipe_id: '',
    pagination: {},
    edit: false
  }
},

created() {
  this.fetchArticles();
}, 

methods: {
  fetchArticles(page_url) {
    let vm = this;
    page_url = page_url || '/api/articles'
    fetch(page_url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      this.articles = res.data;
      vm.makePagination(res.meta, res.links);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },

  makePagination(meta, links) {
    let pagination = {
      current_page : meta.current_page,
      last_page : meta.last_page,
      next_page_url : links.next,
      prev_page_url : links.prev
    };

    this.pagination = pagination;
  }
}
```

Comment: My answer will help you, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51084685/1292050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bound attribute is parsed as javascript. So if you want the string `images/articles/123.jpg` for article `123` you need to pass it to the `:src` attribute like so:

```
<img :src="`images/articles/${article.id}.jpg`" />
```

or

```
<img :src="'images/articles/' + article.id + '.jpg'" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but neither of the two methods above appear to work. I've updated the OP with more info.

Comment: Sorry, this did work. I didn't notice there were two types of quotes in succession! `"'` and `'"`

Answer (score 1):

Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a v-bind directive (v-bind:src or :src)

You can bind the image src like this:

```
<img :src="'images/articles/' + article.id  + '.jpg'" />
```

[You can see this working on the screenshot of the fiddle I developed for your answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDLcW.png)

[Check out the Fiddle :)](https://jsfiddle.net/mariahquery/eywraw8t/394626/)