# How do I package a Vue component with a VuePress plugin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress

In [How do I dynamically load a YAML file as an object in a VuePress Vue Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535473/how-do-i-dynamically-load-a-yaml-file-as-an-object-in-a-vuepress-vue-component/66536271#66536271) I created a Vue Component that renders Swagger but requires a YAML loader configured which is done in a plugin.

I want to package this as a single npm package that can be embedded but I can't find it in the [docs](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/writing-a-plugin.html)