# Unable to bind :src property to a dynamic value

Tags: vuejs2

In the main App.vue component have an img element with src property hard coded as shown below:

```
<img 
  src= './assets/Option01.gif'
  alt="Image couln't be loaded"
/>
```

I'm trying to make this a dynamic parameter where, based on certain conditions the displayed image will change. As shown below, I've refactored the code to bind the src property to a variable:

```
<img 
  :src= "image"
  alt="Image couln't be loaded"
/>
```

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedImage: 0,
      images: [
        './assets/Option01.gif',
        './assets/Option02.gif',
        './assets/Option03.gif',
        './assets/Option04.gif',
        './assets/Option05.gif'
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    image(){
      return this.images[this.selectedImage]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Unfortunately the console will log the message
'GET http://localhost:8080/assets/Option01.gif 404 (Not Found)'.

Any idea on how to proceed in order to make it work?

Comment: instead of './assests/etc' try '@/assests'

Comment: perhaps you working on component or page so you must use ../assets/Option01.gif
./ is current directory and ../ is one step back

Comment: You should use absolute path for the image (referring inside the `public` folder) - or a relative one (relative to the webroot, which is denoted by `publicPath` in `vue.config.js`)

Answer (score 0):

As per the info I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645243/static-image-src-in-vue-js-template) other post the function require() is needed before the image URL in order to make it work:

```
<img 
  :src= "require(image)"
  alt="Image couln't be loaded"
/>
```