# Import another file if one doesn't exist in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import

I'm new to React and trying to import some images. However, the image I'm using can be of either `jpg` or `png`, how do I write code that imports the png if it exists or the `jpg` if the `png` doesn't exist, all as one constant similar to how the import keyword is used usually?

```js
import Card from "Card.{png, jpg}"
```

I've tried the following:

```js
let Card = "";
try {
  Card=require("path-to-png");
} catch(_) {
  try {
    Card = require("path-to-jpg")
  } catch(__) {
    Card = ""
  }
}
```

But it returns the same error:
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path-to-jpg' in '...'`

Comment: Of course it will throw an error, but the code is free to ignore it. See [Catch an error on requiring module in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17553386/215552). Of course, that assumes the code is using an actual path to a known location of a file, and not the literal string `"path-to-jpg"`...

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import CardPng from "Card.png"
import CardJpg from "Card.jpg"
const Card = (CardPng ?? CardJpg)
```

There is no way to import from file1 or file2 for the same declaration name

Comment: Won't this cause the same import error?

Comment: Why ? There are from different files, and have different names

Comment: Oh, I don't think I clarified, my bad. It's not both, its only one, either a jpg or a png, not both. If the jpg doesn't exist the CardJpg import doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's possible if it was possible to ignore import errors, but using the above try catch doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This will cause an import error for the file that doesn't exist. You would need to use a dynamic import (i.e. `const CardPng = await import("Card.png");`) with a try/catch, assuming that even works in React.

Comment: As I said, I don't think it's possible. Look into dynamic import: https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports

Comment: With Webpack you can specify modules that should be ignored if they fail to resolve by setting `resolve.fallback['packageName']` to `false` - but I'm not sure how it could work with needing to target any and all `.jpg` files.